# How do I split a string on a delimiter ` in Bash?

Tags: bash, pipe, pipeline

How can I get `modules/bx/motif` only on the following through pipeline?

```
$ find . | grep denied
find: `modules/bx/motif': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simply this, using `sed`:

```
find . 2>&1 | sed 's/^[^:]*: .\(.*\).: Permission denied/\1/p;d'
```

#### or by using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) only,

As your question stand for [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
string=$'find: `modules/bx/motif\047: Permission denied'
echo $string 
find: `modules/bx/motif': Permission denied

part=${string#*\`} 
echo ${part%\'*}
modules/bx/motif
```

Comment: The first line of code is perfect. added another question to pipeline to sudo chmod https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432555/how-to-pipeline-permission-denied-file-folders-into-sudo-chmod-orw . You might be able to help. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect STDOUT (where the errors you want appear) so you can process it with other tools, then throw away STDIN (which contains non-errors that you don't care about) then use `cut` (or any of a hundred other methods) to pull out the bits you need:

```
find . 2>&1 >/dev/null | cut -d"‘" -f2 | cut -d"’" -f1
```

You might also be able to use one of the built-in `find` filters (like `-perm` maybe) to pick out these files, but you'll have to check the `find`q man page for details.

`find . -not -readable` might be helpful in your case.