# How to pipeline Permission denied file/folders into sudo chmod o+rw?

Tags: bash, pipe, sudo, pipeline

The following is perfect to find the `Permission denied file/folder`. Now need to add pipeline to the follows to exec `sudo chmod o+rw`. How to make it work? Thanks.

```
find . 2>&1 | sed 's/^[^:]*: .\(.*\).: Permission denied/\1/p;d'
```

Comment: Why can't you just do `2>/dev/null` over the output of `find` instead of removing with `sed`

Comment: @Inian the result looks not right just do 2>/dev/null

Comment: Can you show us a sample of how `find` output looks like

Comment: @Inian the line of code is from question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49431602/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash/49432024#49432024

Comment: `find ... | sed ... | xargs chmod ...`  or if *spaces* or other special characters `find ...|sed...|tr \\n \\0 | xargs -0 ...`

Comment: @F.Hauri  I know how to use xargs, however need to use sudo in the pipeline.